# jList doesn't return desired string value

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textfield, jlist

I am new in Java, and I've tried to write a simple GUI application that is supposed to return the selected value of a `jList` into a `textfield`.

But instead of the selected text, it returns a memory address like `[Ljava.lang.Object;@675b9599` to the `textField`.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jTextField1.setText(Arsenal.getSelectedValues().toString()); 
}
```

Comment: The event for writing selected value to the textField is:       private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jTextField1.setText(Arsenal.getSelectedValues().toString());
    } //The items in the jList are added manually in the List editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably retrieving the text of the selected element in the `JList` wrong.
You must use the `getSelectedValue()` to retrieve it.

```
String text = (String) myList.getSelectedValue();
```

There is no need to call the `toString()` method as in `myList.getSelectedValue().toString()` since that might cause you a `NullPointerException` if there is no selected value, and the `JList instead returns a`null` value.

Java docs says:

> Returns the value for the smallest selected cell index; the selected
>   value when only a single item is selected in the list. When multiple
>   items are selected, it is simply the value for the smallest selected
>   index. Returns null if there is no selection.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arsenal.getSelectedValues()//Returns Array of Object and Deprecated as well
                   -------
```

Instead use `jList.getSelectedValue()` **Value** Not **Values** which returns selected element.So it should be

```
jTextField1.setText((String)Arsenal.getSelectedValue());
```

If you have added `String` to your `JList` you would even don't need to convert it to `String` as it will return value according to the type of `JList` element.

If you want to get all selected values use `getSelectedValuesList()` instead of `getSelectedValues()` because it's deprecated.

Comment: The downvote was for the `toString()` method, which now is removed, and my downvote has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

`JList` only returns the `Object`.So convert it to the `String`.

```
jList.getSelectedValue().toString();
```

It should work.

Comment: Using `toString()` might cause a `NullPointerException` if there is no selected value in the `JList`, thus returning a `null`.